# Corda coin selection algorithm

Tags: selection, corda

I've noticed the coin selection algorithm just gathers the first UTXOs until there's enough balance. Is there any roadmap to improve this algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We realise that the current algorithm could be improved in many ways. It could use a hash ring or shard the set of states, for example, to make it less likely that two or more flows would simultaneously try and grab the same state.

Up until now, we haven't identified coin selection as a bottleneck, but it is likely to become one as we continue to improve Corda's performance. We will revisit it at that time.

In the meantime, PRs are welcome to improve the algorithm!